# Mermaid support in Nuxt Vue content

Tags: vue.js, mermaid

I'm trying to add mermaid support in my Vue application Followed the steps as suggested [here](https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/1866#issuecomment-1434274988)

You can view the demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-b5xn6w?file=components%2Fcontent%2FMermaid.vue)

Mermaid.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="mermaid" v-if="show">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>

let show = ref(false);

const { $mermaid } = useNuxtApp()

onMounted( async() => {
  show.value = true
  $mermaid().initialize({ startOnLoad: true })
  await nextTick()
  $mermaid().init();
})

</script>
```

And config

```
import mermaid from 'mermaid';

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.provide('mermaid', () => mermaid);
});
```

However the mermaid block was rendering as a code block instead of a graph.

Comment: There is no actual question or problem stated.  Any information you can provide about what is wrong or what debugging you've done is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see just from the demo that you don't have a working mermaid.vue component.  Copying from the [working example](https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/1866#issuecomment-1442360997) from the same github thread you linked:

**Mermaid.vue**

```html
<template>
  <pre ref="el" :style="{ display: rendered ? 'block' : 'none' }">
    <slot />
  </pre>
</template>
```

```js
<script setup>
const slot = useSlots()
const el = ref(null)
const rendered = ref(false)

async function render() {
  if (!el.value) {
    return
  }
  if (el.value.querySelector('svg')) {
    // Already rendered
    return
  }

  // Iterate children to remove comments
  for (const child of el.value.childNodes) {
    if (child.nodeType === Node.COMMENT_NODE) {
      el.value.removeChild(child)
    }
  }
  const { default: mermaid } = await import("mermaid")
  el.value.classList.add('mermaid')
  rendered.value = true
  await mermaid.run({ nodes: [el.value] })
}

onMounted(() => {
  render()
})
</script>
```

```css
<style>
.mermaid rect {
  stroke: #6195ff !important;
  fill: #fff !important;
}

.mermaid .current-doc.node .label {
  color: #fff !important;
}

.mermaid line {
  stroke: #6195ff !important;
}

[data-theme="dark"] .mermaid .flowchart-link {
  stroke: #fff !important;
}

[data-theme="dark"] .mermaid .messageText {
  fill: #fff !important;
}

[data-theme="dark"] .mermaid marker {
  fill: #fff !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}

[data-theme="dark"] .mermaid line {
  stroke: #fff !important;
}
</style>
```

Alos, use `<mermaid>` tag in your .md file

```html
<mermaid>
graph TD;
    A-->B;
    A-->C;
    B-->D;
    C-->D;
</mermaid>
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-b5xn6w-makvrt?file=content%2Findex.md,components%2Fcontent%2FMermaid.vue)

Comment: Thanks @yoduh is there a way to use this with ```mermaid style block